# How to generate Dynamic generation of C++ define calls

Tags: c++

I have the defines with integer values in Cpp code. I need to call them in loop. How do I do that?

```
// Defines:
#define A0 0
#define A1 1
#define A2 2
// ...
#define A50 50

// Now based on loop I need to call these defines
for (int i = 0; i <= 50; i++){
    function_name(A<i>, value);
}
```

Comment: Impossible. Defines = preprocessor. Loop = compiler. Use an array instead. Btw if your defines are just 0...50, why use a define at all.

Comment: may it help you? `#define A(i) i`.call it in a function function_name(A(i),value).

Comment: The defines have much complicated name like select0..select4, safe5 ... safe8 and so on and generated based on project spec. 
I just gave an example. I have to make use of the defines as available

Comment: @VishwasuDeshpande that is not very helpful information. Please provide a better example that demonstrates what you are really struggling with.

Comment: @VishwasuDeshpande Project spec is broken. Somebody should have pointed out the flaws in this approach before signing off on the specification and agreeing to implement it. A spec shouldn't mandate particular implementations, anyway

Answer (score 1):

`#define` macros are evaluated only by the preprocessor before the compiler is invoked. As such, preprocessor macros do not exist at runtime, and cannot be referred to by names that are built up using variables whose values are only known at runtime.

For what you are attempting, you will have to use an array, eg:

```cpp
#define A0 0
#define A1 1
#define A2 2
...
#define A50 50

const int A[51] = {A0, A1, A2, ..., A50};

...

for (int i = 0; i <= 50; i++){
    function_name(A[i], value);
}
```

Comment: The defines have much complicated name like SELECT0..SELECT4, SAFE5 ... SAFE8, SOURCE9... SOURCE15  and so on and generated based on project spec. I just gave an example. I have to make use of the defines as available

Comment: Also I get the information  whether its SELECT, SAFE, SOURCE but must loop through

Comment: @VishwasuDeshpande checkout my comment, is not my comment useful for you in this situation?

Comment: My environment supports embedded Perl that expands on build. Is there a way I can create a string to preprocessor directive map by reading the defines file? I can then query the map?

Comment: @ Ta Quang Tu No it is not. I will not be able to make changes to defines.